# ArcPy - error with updateRow() using UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I am trying to use the UpdateCursor function to run through each field in each row and to compile a string which is then added to the AbvField.
I'm trying to do this in the python window, rather than as a standalone script.

I get the error:
Runtime error : Row: Field updateRow does not exist

I have included all the code except for the subs dict, which is simply a dictionary of species names (keys) and abbreviations (values) with which the script creates the string for the AbvField.
Everything works fine except for the updating the field.

```
TheShapefile="Primary_biodiversity_layer"
AbvField = "Sp1"

Rows=arcpy.UpdateCursor(TheShapefile)

Fields = arcpy.ListFields(TheShapefile)

SpList = []
newDict = {}

for TheRow in Rows:     
        RString = ""
    for TheField in Fields:
        TheFieldName=TheField.name
        TheValue=TheRow.getValue(TheFieldName)
                if TheValue == "":
                    pass
                elif TheValue not in subs.keys():
                    pass
                else:
                    RString += subs[TheValue] + ", "
                    if TheValue not in newDict.keys():
                        newDict[TheValue] = subs[TheValue]
                    else:
                        pass
        TheRow.setValue(AbvField, RString)
        TheRow.updateRow(TheRow)
        del TheRow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation in your code snippet looks a little astray but I think what is giving you the error you reported is that you have:

```
TheRow.updateRow(TheRow)
```

when it should be:

```
Rows.updateRow(TheRow)
```